# Recreating the strip() method using list comprehensions but output returns unexpected result

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to 'recreate' the `str.split()` method in python for fun.

```
def ourveryownstrip(string, character):
    newString = [n for n in string if n != character]
    return newString

print("The string is", ourveryownstrip(input("Enter a string.`n"), input("enter character to remove`n")))
```

The way it works is that I create a function that passes in two arguments: 1) the first one is a string supplied, 2) the second is a a string or char that the person wants to remote/whitespace to be moved from the string. Then I use a list comprehension to store the 'modified' string as a new list by using a conditional statement. Then it returns the modified string as a list.

The output however, returns the entire thing as an array with every character in the string separated by a comma.

Expected output:

```
Boeing 747 Boeing 787
enter character to removeBoeing
The string is ['B', 'o', 'e', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '7', '4', '7', ' ', 'B', 'o', 'e', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '7', '8', '7']
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, yes… list comprehensions produce lists… You might want to `''.join(...)` that list back into a string?

Comment: The problem is that 'Boeing' is a string - not a character

Comment: @deceze I am really confused though. First, when I enter any string like let's saying `helicopters` into 'The US Airforce has many helicopters.' I literally just get back the original string. It just doesn't work. It returns back the original string in list form. If i cant use list comprehension how do I write code where I create a string variable and it the loop takes every individual char and stores it into the new string and then return it. Help

Comment: @BrutusForcus so what do I do

Comment: Your question is contradictory. It seems like you want to re-write the *replace* function rather than *split*. If that's the case then you can use *index* to identify where the replacement is located then slice the string to remove it

Comment: actually, i want to rewrite the split method where if the character is passed into the argument, that character will be removed completely in the passed in string, not replace anything. but its not workings, so could you read my paragraph above and offer any isnight

Comment: @Shah Jacob that isn't what the split method does though. Split takes a character input and splits the string into a list based on that character. While yes it does remove the character from the string, its primary use is to create a list. What you are trying to do is what the `replace()` which will replace all instances of a substring in the initial string, which when you have the substring replaced with an empty string like this `string.replace('Boeing','')` it removes all occurrences of 'Boeing' in the initial string.

Answer (score 1):

What you have set up is checking each individual character in a list and seeing if it matches 'Boeing' which will never be true so it will always return the whole input. It is returning it as a list because using list comprehension makes a list. Like @BrutusForcus said this can be solved using string slicing and the `string.index()` function like this:

```
def ourveryownstrip(string,character):
    while character in string:
        string = string[:string.index(character)] + string[string.index(character)+len(character):]
    return string
```

This will first check if the value you want removed is in your string. If it is then `string[:string.index(character)]` will get all of the string before the first occurrence of the `character` variable value and `string[string.index(character)+len(character):]` will get everything in the string after the first occurrence of the variable value. That will keep happening until the variable value doesn't occur in the string anymore.